# extended hamming code

Tags: forward-error-correction

for the (7,4) Hamming code, I know how to decode a codeword using the syndrome decoding method, by just using the 3 parity bits, and it is correctable if there is just 1 error.

However, for the (8,4) extended Hamming code, I know how to decode the codewords correctly when there is no error or 1 error respectively. However, can we do that for the case of 2 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the transmitted codeword is $\mathbf C$. If no errors occurred, or one error occurred, then $\mathbf C$ is the *unique* codeword
that is at distance $1$ or less from the received word $\mathbf R$, and the decoding algorithm produces $\mathbf C$ as its output. When there are two errors, there is not a
*unique* codeword that is at distance $2$ or less from the received word. *One*
of the codewords at distance $2$ is $\mathbf C$, but there is *at least one other
such codeword*. So,
the decoding algorithm must be devised to handle this case. The possible options
are

- Declare a decoding **failure**, that is, tell the world that an *uncorrectable
  error pattern* has been detected. A less shameful alternative is used in ARQ 
  (automatic-repeat-request) systems in which the receiver sends back a
  NACK signal to the transmitter which then retransmits $\mathbf C$. Thus, 
  the outside world is not told that the transmission is being repeated
  over and over till the decoder is able to successfully decode, though the
  outside world may be able to infer this because it has to wait extra long
  for the next data bits to come out of the decoder.
- Choose *one* of the codewords nearest to $\mathbf R$ and produce this as
  the decoder output. In this instance, the decoding might be *correct* because
  the decoder fortuitously chose $\mathbf C$, or it might be *incorrect*.

It is important to remember that decoding algorithms *can* output a
wrong codeword even when they are fairly certain they got it right.
If $\mathbf C$ is transmitted and the channel error pattern $\mathbf E$
is such that $\mathbf C + \mathbf E = \mathbf R$ happens to be *another*
codeword $\hat{\mathbf C}$, then the decoder output will be 
$\hat{\mathbf C}$ and the decoder might even declare that it is
confident that it has found the right codeword because it did
not find any errors in $\mathbf R$; it matched $\hat{\mathbf C}$
in every bit! Pride, as we are told, goeth before a fall.

---

Finally, turning to the OP's specific question about the
$(8,4)$ extended Hamming code, the decoder can
tell that an *even number* of errors have occurred if the 
XOR sum of the $8$ received bits is $0$ *and* the rest of the
syndrome (the part that is exactly the same as in the 
$(7,4)$ Hamming code)  is nonzero. So, whenever this
happens, the decoder can declare a decoding failure
or send a NACK to the transmitter, or output a codeword.
An easy way out in this last case
is to assume that the overall parity bit
is in error (and thus flip it) and then use the rest of
the nonzero syndrome to correct one error in the other
$7$ bits exactly as if they were from a $(7,4)$ (non-extended)
Hamming code. This will give a codeword $\hat{\mathbf C}$
that is at distance $2$ from $\mathbf R$ and it will even
be the transmitted codeword $\mathbf C$ if there were exactly
two transmission errors, one in the $7$ bits and one in the
overall parity
bit.